# How to open another ListView after one of rows on the previous ListView has been clicked?

Tags: android, listview, monodevelop

I want to know how to open another `ListView` after one of rows on the previous `ListView` has been clicked?

Bee VOA reader could be a good example to see what I'm talking about.

```
List A                          List B
DeskTop Development    --->     Buttons
                                TextView
                                ScrollBar
Mobile 
Graphic
Game
```

So there is one list A on the phone's screen, and there are many topics in the list A
If I clicked on one of the topic,let's say DeskTop Development, then the whole ListView
will be slided away from the screen and the new List B will be presented.

So how to implement it?

Comment: Are you working with Java or C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a new Activity while passing the appropriate data to display the correct information is a good way to do what you're doing. This is a code example of a list of states which goes to a list of cities in the selected state from the previous list. The state listview from the first activity sends the name of the state to the city listview in second activity which displays a list of cities from that state.

```
private ListView lv;
setContentView(R.layout.displaylayout);
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.DisplayList);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DisplayLocationsCities.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("state",lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


              }
            });
```

//////////////////////back button code allowing you to go back to the previous list (close anything that need to be closed in onDestroy()):

```
this.backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {              

                  // equivalent of 'return'
                  finish();
              }
});
```

//////////////////////adding items to your list dynamically:

```
String [] list = {"New York","Illinois","California","Wisconsin"};
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, list));
```

//////////////////////Extra Credit: Layout for each listView item - R.layout.list_item (list_item.xml in the res/layout folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000" android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center">
</TextView>
```

Comment: Hi ice911, thanks a lot for your answer,I am a totally brand new learner for monoDroid, so could you please attach the full codes to this question, I think it would become to a perfect guide for others who have the same problem.  And I would like to allow users to go back to the previous ListView A from the ListView B. I highly appreciate your works.  thanks man ^_^

Comment: Sure! I don't have the code in its entire form, but i can give you a couple more pieces to help you accomplish what you. Check above for the edits.

Comment: You need to concentrate on completing the first activity/list before you move on. Then, you'll understand what is needed to get the next list/activity working. After you've completed the first two, the rest is as easy as copying and pasting. :)

Comment: Listview tutorial: [http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-example/](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-example/)

Comment: thanks a lot man :), I will try to use these code in my app. Before that it would be better if you could kindly give me the explanation about the purpose of Intend object,.putExtra(), and the code fragment of findViewById(R.id.DisplayList).

Comment: intent objects are "transport vehicle" for sending information in Android (most importantly, it'll be how you open a new activity (as above in code). putExtra() allows you to send data (Extras) with your intent...possibly to be used in the next information (as the code shows sending a state to the next activity to display the cities of that state). findViewById() is a function you'll use a lot! It allows you to interact with views (like the listView) of an layout. R.id.DisplayList is the id of the listView, so you can make a connection between the view and the code that makes changes to it.

Comment: @Franva: You should really go through the hello android tutorials, as it's clear you're missing some of the very fundamentals.

Comment: @ice911 Hi ice911, after one year, when reviewing my comments I just found I need to more research first and thank you for your patient for explaining so much for me. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the onListItemClick() method so that on click it starts a new ListActivity. This way the navigation in the menu will be easier as you will be able to use the back button.

Comment: Hi Muad, thanks a lot to your reply. May I create a new activity file for the mentioned ListActivity? Because I would like to divide the codes into different files rather than put mess codes into one big file. And could you please talk more about how to implement the navigation function and menu for a app? Because I need the back button in my app.  best regards ^_^